# Add delay while hitting the API's in promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Below is my code to fetch a list of stores and then it's products

Now the issue is, the API that returns me product list for a store has a rate limiter in place, i.e. 10req/sec. So If get more than 10 stores and I hit for products, the API starts giving me 503 and in the response I get undefined values along with actual values. Is there a way where I can set timeout, i.e. delay the calling for `getProductList` in my case?

Below is the code

```
const shops = response.data
      return Promise.all(
        shops.map((shop) => {
          const id = shop.shop_id
          const shopobj = {
            id,
            name: shop.shop_name,
          }
          return favAPI.checkFavourite(uid, id)
            .then((favData) => {
              shopobj.is_fave_shop = favData

              // Fetch the products of shop
              return getProductList(id, uid)
                .then((responsedata) => {
                  shopobj.products = responsedata.data.products.map(product => ({
                    id:          product.id,
                    name:        product.name,
                  }))
                  return shopobj
                })
                .catch(() => { })
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
        }))
        .then(responses => responses)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Something I can do like this

```
return setTimeout(() => getProductList(id, uid)
                .then((responsedata) => {
                  shopobj.products = responsedata.data.products.map(product => ({
                    id: product.id,
                    name: product.name,
                    price: product.price,
                    image_url: product.image_url,
                    is_wishlist: userWishListProd.indexOf(product.id) > -1,
                    url: product.url,
                    shop_name: product.shop.name,
                    labels: product.labels,
                    badges: product.badges,
                  }))
                  return shopobj
                })
                .catch((err) => { console.error(err.name, err.statusCode, err.message) }), 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would simply return a response with a code (503 in your case) that says "ask again later" and has the amount of time until next available call in the body (ex: `{ remainingTimeout: 3000 }`), and then you would handle the waiting on the front-end.

Comment: I agree, but it would be more "polite" to avoid hitting the rate limit :p

Answer (score 0):

I've created this funky looking function that I've used successfully in the past

```
const rateLimited = perSecond => {
    perSecond = (isNaN(perSecond) || perSecond < 0.0001) ? 0.0001 : perSecond;
    const milliSeconds = Math.floor(1000 / perSecond);
    let promise = Promise.resolve(performance.now());
    const add = cb => promise.then(lastRun => {
        const now = performance.now();
        const diff = now - lastRun;
        if (diff < milliSeconds) {
            promise = promise.thenWait(milliSeconds - diff).then(() => performance.now());
        }
        return promise.then(cb);
    });
    return add;
};
```

Usage in your code .... look for `// ********` for the two places there's an addition and a change to your code

```
// ********
// "create" the rate limited queue
const limitedProductList = rateLimited(10); // 10 per second limit

const shops = response.data;

return Promise.all(
    shops.map((shop) => {
        const id = shop.shop_id
        const shopobj = {
            id,
            name: shop.shop_name,
        }
        return favAPI.checkFavourite(uid, id)
        .then((favData) => {
            shopobj.is_fave_shop = favData
            // ********
            // Fetch the products of shop using the rate limited queue
            return limitedProductList(() => getProductList(id, uid))
            .then((responsedata) => {
                shopobj.products = responsedata.data.products.map(product => ({
                    id: product.id,
                    name: product.name,
                }))
                return shopobj
            })
            .catch(() => {})
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    })
)
.then(responses => responses)
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in my case was the service that caters only 10 request/sec. For that I needed to delay my calls. The solution I got is from a 3rd party library for Promises, i.e. [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

I replaced Promise.all with bluebird's [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

This has a concurrency argument in which you can specify the limit.